# The number of self normalizing subgroup in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group define $f(G)$ be the number of proper subgroups  with the property $N_G(H)=H$.

We can say $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $f(G)=0$. Hence, we can think that when $f(G)$ increase then $G$ beceomes far away from being nilpotent.

I wonder is there any good bound $k$ for $G$ such that $f(G)\leq k\implies G$ is solvable.

**Edit:** By the way it is easy to show  that if $G$ is not nilpotent then $f(G)>2$.

Comment: Since $f(A_5)=21$, and other unsolvable groups seem to be larger, you could conjecture $k=20$.

Comment: Just a remark. Of course proper subgroups containing a normalizer of a Sylow subgroup qualify here. In general, a Carter subgroup of a finite group G is a nilpotent self-normalizing subgroup. These subgroups were introduced by Roger Carter, and initiated new research in the theory of solvable groups. Carter (1961) proved that any finite *solvable* group has a Carter subgroup, and all its Carter subgroups are conjugate subgroups. If a group is not solvable it need not have any Carter subgroups: for example, $A_5$ has no Carter subgroups.

Comment: In further support of 20, there are many other examples of small unsolvable groups with $f(G) = 21$, and none with a smaller value among groups in the SmallGroups database (except that I didn't check the 588 unsolvable groups of order 1920).